# Should I start abbreviations with capital letters in titles?

Tags: abbreviations, capitalization

The title of a section in my paper is

> Bipolar Disorder Def.

Should it be "Def." or "def."?

Comment: You will find numerous guides on the internet if you google CAPITAL LETTERS IN TITLES, including this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized

Comment: A section of a paper should not be abbreviated!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be Definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "def" an abbreviation of? *Defined*, *definition*, *definite* or *[**definitely**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/def)*?

Is there a good reason why an abbreviation must be used in a title?

It is my belief that abbreviations should be avoided in titles unless they are works of literature or newspaper articles. Write the term in full, it's very likely that you're only going to use it once.

1. Definition of Bipolar Disorder
2. [**Bipolar Disorder Definition**](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/conditions/bipolar-disorder)
3. Bipolar Disorder Defined
4. Bipolar Disorder Definitely (This last one is meant to be a joke)

Comment: A few days ago, the OP asked an earlier question about the abbreviation of _definition_ (it has since been closed as general reference and deleted by the OP). Therefore, I'm pretty sure that "definition" is the right answer to your question. Nevertheless, you raise a very pertinent point: with the scant information found in this question, there is no way to know that (unless you happened to have seen the earlier question). The answer to your query should have [def.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/def) been furnished in the original question!

Comment: @J.R. that would explain the downvotes and the silence the question received. Good to know. Thanks.